# How to unbrick BIOS on Dell Precision M4500

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bios, dell-precision

I looked at the other similar questions. They were either about a different brand, outdated, or spam. Do not worry, I haven't bricked my BIOS yet.

---

I was planning to flash my BIOS to a later version due to minor issues (power saving tactics when plugged in, BIOS password errors, slow POST, etc.) with it. I am currently running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I am holding off on flashing because I do not know how to recover from a failed flash. It is better to know before than to be desperate when the knowledge is needed. Here are my specs:
  OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
  CPU: Intel Core i7 @1.732 GHz  Memory: 8 GB DDR3 RAM
  Model: Dell Precision M4500
  Service tag: fc1jfq1

Answer (score 1):

I found this relevant discussion about a Dell Precision M4600 (not M4500) BIOS "failure". It talks about a Dell Signature Firmware 'feature' that was introduced into a number of laptops which caused problems with future BIOS upgrades. It's not that the BIOS fails and bricks the motherboard. It seems the BIOS can't authenticate the new BIOS and simply won't upgrade it.

The Precision M4500 (yours) ***is listed*** in the PDF file linked there as supporting the Signed Firmware Update feature. Just FYI to help you decide to upgrade...

Here is the discussion:
http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3524/t/19564156

Answer (score 1):

Depending on at what point the bios flash failed during the flash procedure what can be done.

If it is a soft fail you can recover by powering down, remove the battery and AC power, hold the power button down for 15 seconds, connect ac and see if the bios will load.

Hard fail: (Bios Brick) Different models have different procedures for doing a bios "crisis recovery", I cannot find one for your specific model but here is an Example of what was done for some older Dell models, so recovery may be possible if you can find the specific procedure for your model, Dell does not release this information anymore, it is now discovered by trial and error and gets posted on the internet hopefully.

> 1. Download your bios file from Dell
> 2. Extract HDR file from EXE: xxxxxx.exe -writehdrfile, a file xxxxxx.hdr will be there;
> 3. Copy xxxxxx.hdr to a formatted floppy disk;
> 4. Unplug AC adapter and battery from the bricked laptop;
> 5. Plug USB-Floppy with the disk prepared;
> 6. Holding press "END" on the keyboard, plug AC Adapter;
> 7. Then you will find that the battery light is on with red;
> 8. Release "END", you will find the power light is on and laptop power up;
> 9. Keep waiting... USB-Floppy will start to work. A continuous reading instead of a short seek action. Keep waiting...
> 10. Finally, the lapop shutdown or restart.
>       That is all, power on again, you will find it is working properly.
>       While the key point is the hdr file, what filename it shold be in the floppy disk, this is different with laptop type/model.
>
> For D620 and later, *.hdr and *.bin can be accepted;
>   For D610, AZED????BIN, AZED????HDR, AZED????HDC, AZE?????BIN, AZE?????HDR, can be accepted.
>
> For D410, VENI????BIN, VENI????HDR, VENI????HDC, VEN?????BIN, VEN?????HDR, can be accepted.
>   ...
>
> So the upper step 3, you have to rename the file to the right filename on the floppy.
>
> And where you can find the exact filename, you can winhex or other hex editor on the .hdr or .rom file and search "hdr".

On newer laptops this would done using a flash drive not a floppy drive.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the term "[Bricked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_%28electronics%29)" (when used correctly) means that the device is absolutely un-repairable, without replacing hardware.

In the case of a Flash-gone-wrong, there is nothing that can be done, short of replacing the EPROM that contains the system firmware (BIOS or EFI) or using specialized equipment to flash the firmware after removing it from the motherboard.

Some motherboards implement a [dual-BIOS](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/d/dualbios.htm), which allows a backup BIOS chip take over if the first is corrupted. These systems are rather resilient to bricking as there is always a bios capable of loading the system enough to reflash the primary chip.

Most motherboard manufacturers provide software utilities to flash a bios from within the booted OS. It is generally recommended that you use these utilities, rather than booting from a floppy, so as to reduce the dependence on peripheral hardware, and provide the maximum degree of initial validation and checking prior to attempting the flash.

Comment: So... How do I tell if my board has dual-BIOS?

Comment: Dell's do not have dual bios's.

Comment: generally your best bet with big-box distributors like Dell is to contact support. They can help you determine the exact model of your motherboard, and you can then look for manufacturer documentation. The issue at hand is that any given laptop sku may have many different internal components, and only the builder has the full list or can tell you which is in your specific model.